# Chrome is not accepting my IIS self-signed certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I'm developing on my local machine with a self-signed certificate in IIS.
Everytime I open Chrome and go to my site, initially I get an error 'Your connection is not private'.
I then have to click 'Advanced' and 'Proceed to [sitename]'. I don't want to perform that manual action every time. Also I want to run via https on my local machine, so please no advice of not doing that.

I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate): Exporting the certificate to a file and then importing it in Chrome.

I see the certificate in my Trusted Root Certificate Authorities.
Also when I now click the lock icon in my address bar I see this:

[image]

[image]

I already restarted Chrome, but keep getting this message. What can I do?

Comment: what are the specifics of the error (the certificate window is covering it in the screenshot)?  Could be a number of issues.

Comment: Just to confirm you installed it correctly.  Does it work how you want it in IE?

Comment: @JimG.: image added

Comment: @Ramhound IE also warns me, but also in Chrome when I click continue I can access the site over https. So it should be okay right?

Comment: Is it secure, of course it is, you just have not trusted the certificate hence the warning.  Can you located the certificate within the certmgr for the user your using? `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items`?  Windows is indicating based on the error the certificate is NOT in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store for either the Machine or the User.

Comment: @Ramhound ah, I see the `localhost` certificate under Personal, but not under `Trusted`...how can I move it there?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this post is old. Here is the answer:

**Why is this happening?**
The commonName was deprecated in RFC 2818 (published in 2000), but support still remains in a number of TLS clients including Internet Explorer.
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4981025180483584

**What do I need to do?**
You need to issue a web certificate using Certificates MMC console for Computer account and specify the san: attribute.

**Refer to the Microsoft article below:**
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625722(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: The Microsoft article is missing the creation of the "select certificate enrollment policy" between step 11 and 12